# Extract Text from Powerpoint

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint, extract

So, I have found this nice Script here:
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00274_Export_Text_to_a_text_file-_extract_text_from_PowerPoint_-Mac_or_PC-.htm
(I'm using the second one)

The import part is this:

```
 For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes                'Loop thru each shape on slide
      'Check to see if shape has a text frame and text
      If oShp.HasTextFrame And oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
        If oShp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            Select Case oShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderTitle, ppPlaceholderCenterTitle
                    Print #iFile, "Title:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderBody
                    Print #iFile, "Body:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderSubtitle
                    Print #iFile, "SubTitle:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Else
                    Print #iFile, "Other Placeholder:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
            End Select
        Else
            Print #iFile, vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
        End If  ' msoPlaceholder
      Else  ' it doesn't have a textframe - it might be a group that contains text so:
        If oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
            sTempString = TextFromGroupShape(oShp)
            If Len(sTempString) > 0 Then
                Print #iFile, sTempString
            End If
        End If
      End If    ' Has text frame/Has text

    Next oShp
```

I have already modified it a bit, so the output file does not contain "Title", "Other Placeholder" and such text and neither inserts tabs ("vbTab"). However, it puts each line (or parapgraph) into a new line in the outfile.

**The Question:** How can I tell the script to dump all 'content' from a 'slide'/'body' into the same line/cell?

I noticed that this script (and neither this http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00332_Export_Slide_Number_and_Title_Text_to_a_text_file.htm) exhibits this behavior for titles, only for "body" or "ppPlaceholderBody".

I have no clue why that is or what the difference is. Can it simply not tell the difference between two lines or bulletins even in the same shape/box?
My goal is to have a consistent line/cell numbering over multiple .ppts so that one added line in slide 2 does not result content from slide 5 to be shifted to the next line.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

My PowerPoint installation is down at the moment, so this is untested. But...

You just need to create a string variable and add to it, then when you're finished with the slide, copy that string to an Excel cell.

```
Dim slideText As String
For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes                 'Loop thru each shape on slide
    If Len(slideText) > 0 Then
        '--- strip the unneeded trailing CRLF
        slideText = Left$(slideText, Len(slideText) - 2)
        '--- now copy the string to the appropriate cell in Excel
    Else
        '--- clear the string for the next slide
        slideText = vbNullString
    End If

    'Check to see if shape has a text frame and text
    If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
        If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            If oShp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                Select Case oShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                    Case Is = ppPlaceholderTitle, ppPlaceholderCenterTitle
                        slideText = slideText & "Title:" & vbTab & _
                                    oShp.TextFrame.TextRange & vbCrLf
                    Case Is = ppPlaceholderBody
                        slideText = slideText & "Body:" & vbTab & _
                                    oShp.TextFrame.TextRange & vbCrLf
                    Case Is = ppPlaceholderSubtitle
                        slideText = slideText & "SubTitle:" & vbTab & _
                                    oShp.TextFrame.TextRange & vbCrLf
                    Case Else
                        slideText = slideText & "Other Placeholder:" & _
                                    vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange & vbCrLf
                End Select
            Else
                slideText = slideText & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
            End If                           ' msoPlaceholder
        End If
    Else
        ' it doesn't have a textframe - it might be a group that contains text so:
        If oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
            sTempString = TextFromGroupShape(oShp)
            If Len(sTempString) > 0 Then
                slideText = slideText & sTempString & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    End If                                   ' Has text frame/Has text
Next oShp

'--- catch the text on the last slide here
If Len(slideText) > 0 Then
    '--- strip the unneeded trailing CRLF
    slideText = Left$(slideText, Len(slideText) - 2)
    '--- now copy the string to the appropriate cell in Excel
End If
```

Of course, you're doing this loop for each slide.

Comment: Good one, @PeterT.  It might be necessary to get a little trickier to get rid of line endings, eg by using Replace(oShp.TextFrame.TextRange,VBCRLF,"") and possibly the same for Chr$(11), which PPT uses for line endings in some placeholder types.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you so much for your solution.
As a preface, everything I know about VB and Macros is from examples online.
1) I don't really understand how
~~~
 If Len(slideText) > 0 Then
        '--- strip the unneeded trailing CRLF
~~~
removes CRLF... but okay.
However your solutions gives me an empty output file..
I noticed how you removed the print part here
~~~
Case Is = ppPlaceholderTitle, ppPlaceholderCenterTitle
                    Print #iFile, "Title:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
~~~

Comment: (accidentally hit Enter)
compared to: ~~~ slideText = slideText & "Title:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange & vbCrLf ~~~

But simply adding it back in does not seem to be the way to go, it gives an output file with "WRONG" cells. Thanks again.

Comment: okay, hold on, I get it know. I understand how Len + Left -2 works now.
But the " '--- now copy the string to the appropriate cell in Excel" / Print #iFile is still missing / not working, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this helps, but this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468824/printing-from-ppt-vba-to-an-excel-spreadsheet
tries something similar using Lbound and Ubound to print to specific cells.

As long as the cells remain consistent over multiple ppt/xls, I don't really where the strings go...

(Though it also selects a specific xls file, while I want to create a new one for each print out, but that should no be a problem with the code I already have which either creates a specified file or uses the filename from the ppt.)